# Accessing MySQL DATABASE from Python hosted on cloud

Tags: python, mysql, cloud, mysql-python

I have a MySQL server installed locally and I have Python code that accesses MySQL Database and executes a simple query:

```
from mysql.connector import connect
from mysql.connector import ProgrammingError

DB = {
   'user':'andrei',
   'password':'qwertttyy',
   'host':'localhost', 
   'port':'3306', 
   'db':'my_database'
}


class Connection:

    instance = None 

    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls.instance:
            try:
                cls.instance = connect(**DB)
            except:
                raise 
        return cls.instance 

    

def excuteDQL(query):
    cnx = Connection()
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        return cursor.fetchall() 
    except ProgragrammingError as err:
        print('You have an error in your MySQL syntax. Please check and retry')
        return [] 
        


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        query = input('Enter a SQL query: ')
        for tuple in executeDQL(query):
            print(tuple)
```

If I go out there and find a cloud MySQL hosting service and pay for it, the access would be as easy as changing the DB mapping with different info?

**I think it should be because the connection would still be over standard TCP/IP, except, in this case, it happens to come back the same machine that is emitting**. I guess, under the hood, data is packed following TCP/IP rules up to the IP layer, and then these are transferred as IP Packets from the Python process through the OS Networking API to the MySQL Server listening to the port, without further down processing into the Access Layer since the packets never leave the machine, which I understand is the purpose of the Access Layer of the TCP/IP stack, that is, to abstract the physical road the data takes.

Did I say something coherent in my guessing?

If I'm wrong, How can I put a MySQL Server in the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes how you connect to the database would not change. It will be as simple as changing the host name and providing whatever credentials you need ( Access Token , User info, etc). The way you insert data doesn't change once you make a connection to the DB.

Here is a good script which should provide some info: https://gist.github.com/kirang89/7161185

Comment: I’ve already signed into a MySQL serving hosting, these days I’ll test the python code with the credentials they provided to me. Thanks .

Comment: It worked. As simple as that. I wonder why I did not put my database there before.